# How to access Sitecore item from standalone WCF service

Tags: wcf, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a WCF service independent of Sitecore ( outside sitecore folder structure) , in which i am creating new items to the sitecore master database. While doing this i am getting configuration errors and Database null.

Below are the Code , reference of sitecore.kernel and bin directory.

[image: Reference in VS project]

[image: Bin Folder]

[image: Code]

[image: Exception]

Exception Details:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

Any Help how to access the Sitecore from outside the folder structure of Sitecore.

Comment: Must admit I've fallen victim to this recently. Sitecore is reliant on the web.config for most things. I think you'll need to push that business logic back over to the business layer of your web app.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have a WCF service independent of Sitecore, but according to your code it is far from independent of Sitecore.

Either move the WCF service into the Sitecore solution so you can have a Sitecore Context etc.
Or make the WCF service independent and connect from the WCF service to Sitecore through the `Sitecore Item Web Api` or a custom webservice inside your Sitecore solution to create the new items.

Sitecore Item Web Api reference: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf

Comment: Independent here means , that i am not having WCF in sitecore solution.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do it. I have tried myself to recreate Sitecore's context in another application and I failed.

I would suggest you to use the Sitecore's Item Web Api or Sitecore's Web Services to manipulate items.

Here some references:

Sitecore Item Web Api reference:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf

A C# client, make things easier: 
http://sitecorecreative.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/sitecore-web-api-client-library/

Sitecore Web services:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/Sitecore_Web_Service_SC65_A4.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't recomment using the Sitecore Web Services, use the Sitecore Item Web Api if you can.

Comment: You are right, I also wouldn`t go this way too for most scenarios, I`ve added as an existent option. I have used that client I mentioned and it made my life easier..

Answer (score 0):

If you check out my blog I have referenced the way to do it.  There are two ways both use the web services.  You are not directly accessing Sitecore Context.

http://sitecoreguild.blogspot.ca/2014/02/accessing-sitecore-item-from-external.html